# Create an Exe with PyInstaller using a script with Gooey and Joblib

Tags: python, pyinstaller, joblib

I try to create an executable with PyInstaller. The script is composed of a GUI created with Gooey and a parallelism made with Joblib. When I run the code alone, it works fine. But when I encapsulate it to make an executable, it opens the GUI as many times as there are workers and does not execute the code.

The script :

```
import sys
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend

@Gooey(program_name="GUI Example App")
def get_args():

    parser = GooeyParser(description="v1")

    parser.add_argument(
        "text",
        metavar="Input Text",
        help="Text to be processed",
        type=str,
        default="",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def get_ascii(index , c):
    c_ascii = ord(c)
    print(f"{index}: The ASCII value of given character {c} is {c_ascii}")

def run(args):
    print(args.text)

    Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=10, prefer='processes')(
        delayed(get_ascii)(i, c)
        for i, c in enumerate(args.text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_args()
    run(args)
```

The spec file

```
import gooey
gooey_root = os.path.dirname(gooey.__file__)
gooey_languages = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'languages'), prefix = 'gooey/languages')
gooey_images = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'images'), prefix = 'gooey/images')

a = Analysis(
    ['parall_gooey.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=None,
    runtime_hooks=None,
    )

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

options = [('u', None, 'OPTION')]

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    gooey_languages, # Add them in to collected files
    gooey_images, # Same here.,
    name='parall_gooey',
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    debug=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False
)
```

I found several solutions on the Internet but nothing solved the problem

- `from multiprocessing import freeze_support` then after `if __name__ == "__main__":` put `freeze_support()`
- `parallel_backend("threading")` : works but becomes extremely long.
- reduce the number `n_core` in `Parallel()`.
- `pre_dispatch='1.5 * n_jobs'` in`Parallel()`
- `hiddenimports=['joblib']` in  spec file